# Date difference between the first date and rest of the dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2012

I have a table with Date column,just as shown below

```
|Date      |
|----------|
|2019-01-11|
|2019-01-12|
|2019-01-13|
|2019-01-14|
|2019-01-15|
```

Output

```
|Date      |Difference|
|----------|----------|
|2019-01-11|    0     |
|2019-01-12|    1     |
|2019-01-13|    2     |
|2019-01-14|    3     |
|2019-01-15|    4     |
```

Can anyone help or suggest a way to achieve this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the difference with the smallest date for each row, you can do a window `min()`:

```
select date, datediff(day, min(date) over(), date) difference
from mytable
order by date
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like `row_number()`:

```
select output,
       row_number() over (order by date) - 1 as difference
from t;
```

If you wanted the difference from the earliest:

```
select output,
       datediff(day, min(date) over (), date)
from t;
```